# How to run jhipster command from a java program

Tags: java, jhipster, jhipster-registry

I'm trying to run the **jhipster import-jdl** command from a java program as show below.

```
public boolean generate(String foldername, String filename) {

        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

        try {
            IPath root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation();
            Process proc = rt.exec(new String[] { "cmd", "/K",
                    "cd " + root + "\\" + foldername + " && jhipster import-jdl " + filename });

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        return true;

    }
```

But the entity files are not getting created.

But if I open the command prompt in the folder specified in the code and run the same command as shown below manually, the entity files are generated.

> **cd C:\GitClone\work && jhipster import-jdl swaggertest.jh**

I'm new to these things and have no idea on where am I going wrong. Please help me with the same.

Comment: Is there any error?  Did you wait for the `Process` to complete?  One way to do that is https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor--

Comment: I checked the log for errors but there are none! And I'm making sure that the Process is getting completed.